Python app using cupy and cupyx fails with cl.exe not found: how to package to work with no cl.exe on target machine
The app is built in Python on Windows 10 and make heavy use of cupy and cupyx.scipy.ndimage, and a few other cupyx libraries: It is distributable and it works. It now needs to go to a more secure location with no internet access, and no C++ installed on the computer. When I tried to run the app, I got a Cl.exe not found error. Not a surprise in retrospect.
Cupy has a cache directory for code compiled on the build/test/development machine. I tried to distribute that cached code with the app, making sure I set the new path on the target machine, but that did not help. Still got the cl.exe not found.
I even tried this on my development machine by running my code, then setting the CUPY_CACHE_DIR to the correct path, then disabling cl.exe, and re-running the exact same code, same data, same OS obviously. still failed with cl.exe not found. I guess I'm confused, what is the cache for if not to speed up the code and avoid compiling if it is already compiled. Is there no way to distribute a complete and fully compiled system so no C++ (cl.exe) is needed on the target computer?
I'm using cupy 12.3.0, Windows 10, NVidia Cuda 11.8, visual studio 2022
Building distribution with PyInstaller and Innosetup.
Thanks David

Ship a wheel instead of building from source.

Normally I think of wheels as being used for pip installed packages rather than fully packaged executables; And I don't see how or if it would solve my cupy/cupyx problem, but I can take a look.  Let me know if you have any suggestions as to how to speed up the process in terms of tooling, etc. Thanks.

The main problem seemed to have been a cupy bug (or feature) that was fixed in version 13.2.0 which was released last Thursday (6/13/24). This was first reported in issue #8342, "cupy do not suport two axis operation?", and again in issue #8380, "Certain calls in cupy/cupyx always require a c++ compiler on Windows despite precompiled kernels"
